# Reset Angle using Jquery-ui-rotatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I'm using jQuery UI Rotatable to be able to rotate objects. I am trying to implement and button that will reset the rotation to it's starting angle. I cannot seem to get it to work. Any thoughts? Here is my code and a link.
 https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable

HTML:

```
<button id="btn1"> Button </button>

<divs id="draggable2">
    <div id="target2" style="width: 250px; padding: 1px; padding-right: 1px">
    <img  id="target2" src="https://s33.postimg.org/dr29dnyb3/rightarm2.gif">
    </div>
```

JS

```
 $('#target2').rotatable({angle: 0.5}); $('#draggable2').draggable();

    $('#btn1').click(function () {
    $('#target2').ui.angle.current = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out.  This will fix your problem:

To set the angle of element with ID 'target' to 1 radian, do this:

```
$('#target').data('uiRotatable').angle(1.0)
```

Need it in degrees? Let's say you wanted to set it to 30 degrees ...

```
$('#target').data('uiRotatable').angle(Math.PI * 30 / 180)
```

Combine with the jQuery bind() function to do whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured this out if anyone ever needs to know. 
https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable/issues/13